# Google maps API get GPS coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, google-maps-api-2

I try to get GPS coordinates of some places via Google Map API but it doesn't work.
Here an example:
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Hungary,%20Szeged&hl=en&key=MY_API_KEY
Where is MY_API_KEY gets from the Google APIs Console. I have also switched on the Google Maps API v2, Google Maps API v3 and Google Maps Coordinate API.
When I load the URL I get this:

```
{
  "Status": {
    "code": 610,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
}
```

610 means wrong API key.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Hungary,%20Szeged&sensor=false

Comment: Thank You! Its much better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the deprecated v2 API, use the current [Google Maps Geocoding API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)